# How to get particular column data from mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this,

```
tid vid emp_id  stop_time   dates
----------------------------------------
1   5680      6 01:00 am    2017-05-19
2   5680      6 04:00 am    2017-05-19
3   5680      3 07:00 am    2017-05-19
4   5680      3 05:00 pm    2017-05-19
5   5680      6 08:00 am    2017-05-20
```

I want the particular value, for above this e.g i need this values **04:00 am and 05:00 pm** and **08:00 am**. That means i need last enter value of **emp_id** also particular dates based.

Demo data:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f6e59/1

Comment: if id is auto_increment means just do this selec max(tid) ,emp_id from table where date=particular_date gorup by emp_id

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: yes id is auto_incr but that solution not working @JYoThI

Comment: not working means did you getting any error ?

Comment: means i get wrong output e.g i got this things, 01:00 am and 07:00 am,(i tried this  "select max(tid) ,emp_id, stop_time from third_table where dates='2017-05-19' group by emp_id") @JYoThI

Comment: yea updated in sqlfiddle @Strawberry

Comment: explain why down voted? @downvoters

Comment: If you hover over the down arrow, it sometimes provides a clue.

Comment: select * from third_table where tid in (select max(tid) from third_table where dates='2017-05-19' group by emp_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **subquery**

```
select * from third_table 
where tid in (select max(tid) from third_table 
              where dates between '2017-05-19' and '2017-05-20' group by emp_id,dates)
```

Comment: because it's date is 2017-05-20   @teddycherrykj

Comment: yes but i tried with `between` but when i use between `05:00 pm' is missing

Comment: sure `select * from third_table 
where tid in (select max(tid) from third_table 
              where dates between '2017-05-19' and '2017-05-20' group by emp_id) `

Comment: try this  select * from third_table where tid in (select max(tid) from third_table where dates between '2017-05-19' and '2017-05-20' group by emp_id,dates)  @teddycherrykj

Comment: i already updated . if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @teddycherrykj